# Celery - Received unregistered task of type

Tags: python, celery

I'm trying to run the example from http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html. It works fine locally, however when I try to run it on a server I get

```
[2015-06-24 19:55:39,758: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'tasks.add'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you are using relative imports?
Please see http://bit.ly/gLye1c for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
{'utc': True, 'chord': None, 'args': (4, 4), 'retries': 0, 'expires': None, 'task': 'tasks.add', 'callbacks': None, 'errbacks': None, 'timelimit': (None, None), 'taskset': None, 'kwargs': {}, 'eta': None, 'id': '67f1dc13-e788-4558-a470-415288045eb2'} (209b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 455, in on_task_received
    strategies[name](message, body,
KeyError: 'tasks.add'
```

I've searched throughout stack overflow and tried all the solutions mentioned, however still have no luck.

Thanks in advance

**NOTE:** Celery is in fact finding my tasks

```
[tasks]
  . tasks.add
```

So I really don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: please add a snippet from the module where you declare your celery tasks.

Comment: also - that code snippet which you say shows that celery is finding your tasks - where is that from ?